# Ontext Changed event not firing for TextBox

Tags: asp.net

I have a TextBox beside which I have a Search Button. On click of the Search Button, it pops up a page where user selects the value and that value is automatically populated in the TextBox beside the Search Button. Now, based on the value automatically populated in the TextBox, there are other dynamic controls populated on the page.

I am using `TextBox.TextChanged` event , I am calling the method which populates the other dynamic controls.

However, the OnTextBox_changed event is firing only when I press the tab key or enter key from that TextBox but I want it to fire once a text is populated.

Below is my aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtGL1" runat="server" Text="" AutoPostBack="true"
 Enabled="true" EnableViewState="true" ontextchanged="txtGL1_TextChanged">
</asp:TextBox>

protected void txtGLAccount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateControls();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Text change event works like that only.

> The TextChanged event is raised when
>   the content of the text box changes
>   between posts to the server.

More details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx). If you want to do something on as you type you need to use KeyPress / Keydown / Keyup javascript events.

Comment: I am trying to understand youranswer I am not typing the value in the textbox manually rather the value is populated automatically which of the event will help me fire the textbox event

Comment: value is populated automatically ? means autocompleting? then I think you need to set the autocompelete property to false to make it work. - Here is the MS Support link - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/873198

Answer (score 0):

If the text box is inside an ajax update panel then also the event will not fired. If you also have similar issue then  add a trigger in the update panel for that text box and it will work.
From design also double click on that textbox to verify that no new event method is generating.In case if found delete the old TextChanged event and add it in this Method.